# Simple rewrite.. but it does not work?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i have this simple rewrite in my apache server that doesn't work...

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /?lang=IT [L]
```

what i hope to do is write in the browser address bar

www.mywebsite.com

and have the variable "lang" passed in GET.

Does anyone have a hint please ?

Comment: What happens if you change the flags to `[R,L]`?

Comment: unfortunately the page still do not get the "lang" variable.

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine On` set? Out of ideas otherwise, rule looks fine to me.

Comment: Yup, RewriteEngine On is set ! I'm really out of ideas too ! I even removed all other rules, but still no luck !

Comment: Last one... mod_rewrite enabled?!

Comment: Yes, other rules works fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your rule will only work with `www.mywebsite.com/` (with a slash).

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ ?lang=IT [L]
```